# Getting $n<\epsilon$ when trying to show that a limit converges by the definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have the following question:

> Use the definition of a limit to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n^2+2n}-n=1$

My attempt:

We need to find $n_0$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0$ we have $| \sqrt{n^2+2n}-n-1|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$

We know that  $\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n-1<n^2+n-1<n^2+n\leq2n^2$ (which is positive so we can remove the absolute value)

$2n^2<\epsilon\Longrightarrow n<\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$

My problem is that since, we need $n<\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ the inequality won't true and I got stuck here,what to do? did I go wrong anywhere? I am used to getting results like $n>\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ for example.

Edit: I tried verifying that the result of the limit is correct and it looks like it is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+approaches+infinity+of+sqrt%28n%5E2%2B2n%29-n

Comment: Your estimates are simply too rough. Either you'll have to find sharper estimates or otherwise an entirely different approach.

Comment: If $\varepsilon > |\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}-n-1|$ and also $2n^2>|\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}-n-1|$ this doesn't tell us anything about the bound of $\varepsilon$ wrt. $n$, to point out the mistake.

Comment: @jasnee I tried using $n^2+2n+1$ as well and it resulted in a similar result

Comment: @MDude my idea was if I find $n$ such that $2n^2<\varepsilon$ then the main equation will be <$\varepsilon$ as well

Comment: You need to state the definition much more carefully, with the words in the right order! _Any_ sequence $(a_n)$ and number $L$ satisfy "$\forall n\geq n_0$ we have $| a_n-L|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$" (proof: let $\epsilon=2|a_n-L|$). Luckily that does **not** say $\lim a_n=L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequalities do not yield a proof.

Verify, by squaring,  the following: $1+\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {2n^{2}} \leq\sqrt {1+\frac 2 n}\leq 1+\frac 1 n$. Multiply by $n$ and conclude that $\sqrt {n^{2}+2n} -n-1 \in [-\frac 1 {2n},0]$. Hence, it is enough to take $n$ such that $\frac 1 {2n} <\epsilon$ which means $n >
\frac 1 {2\epsilon}$.

Comment: How did you arrive to this inequality in the first place? can you explain further?

Comment: @Sergio $(1+x)^{1/2}=1+\frac  1  2 /x+\frac {(1/2)(1/2-1)} 2/x^{2}+..$ (The Taylor expansion) for $|x|<1$. From this it is easy to guess that inequalities of the type I used must hold.

Comment: @Sergio In Taylor expansion take $x=\frac  2 n$. BTW there was a mistake in the inequalities I wrote earlier and I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is my solution wrong because of having a very rough estimate?

Comment: @Sergio Yes, it is often tempting to write down some obvious inequalities  which may not yield  a proof (even though the inequalities are correct).

Comment: This was the only method I was taught and I tried so many estimates that led to nowhere